# Rotation when flipping up vector from Y to Z

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation, transform, glm-math

I have a rotation problems.

I have the camera set up so that up vector is Z, -X is forward and right is Y. I have models that are exported in another coordinate system where Y is up, -Z is forward, X is right.

My challenge/problem is with rotation. How to do correct rotation in this case without changing the coordinate system of objects that I import. Scale and transform are working as they should.

So far I have tried swapping Y and Z axis in the rotation matrix manual, doing the rotation matrix separately, doing the rotation as we read control file, flipping Z and Y rotation axis, changing the matrix to

| 1 0 0 |

| 0 0 1 |

| 0 1 0 |

etc.

PS. I dont want to change the coordinate system of the object files that I import now and when I write in the control file rotateY it will rotate the object in my Y axis not the object Y axis.

This is the part of code I am trying the transformations

```
// control file is where i store transform, rotate and scale in a text file and objects that i want to read. 
for(int i = 0; i< controls.size(); i++) {
        meshStruct tempMesh;

        int isMeshLoaded = loadObjFile((char*)controls[i].path, &tempMesh.objectInfo_, &tempMesh.numObjects_);
        if(isMeshLoaded)
        {
            cout<< "Mesh " << controls[i].path << " loaded sucesfully." << endl;
        } else {
            cout<< "Mesh " << controls[i].path << " loaded failed." << endl;
        }

        tempModelMatrix = mat4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        //mat4 tempModelMatrixFlip = mat4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        //                              0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        //                              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        //                              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        //tempModelMatrix *= tempModelMatrixFlip;

        tempModelMatrix = glm::translate(tempModelMatrix, controls[i].translate);

        tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.x), vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        // I dont want to flip here Y and Z because some objects are in the correct coordinate system
        tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.y), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
        tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.z), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)); 
        /*
        mat4 r  = mat4(1.0f);
        mat4 rx = mat4(1.0f); 
        mat4 ry = mat4(1.0f);
        mat4 rz = mat4(1.0f);
        rx = rotate(radians(controls[i].rotation.x), vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        ry = rotate(radians(controls[i].rotation.y), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
        rz = rotate(radians(controls[i].rotation.z), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
        r = rx * ry * rz;       

        vec4 temp;

        temp = column(r, 1);
        cout << to_string(temp) << endl;
        r = column(r,1, column(r, 2));
        r = column(r,2, temp);

        temp = row(r,1);
        r = row(r, 1,row(r,2));
        r = row(r, 2, temp);
        //cout << to_string(column(tempModelMatrix, 1)) << endl;

        //tempModelMatrix *= r;
        float tempModelMatrix2[16];// = mat4(1.0f);

        tempModelMatrix2[0] =  controls[i].scale.x * column(r, 0).x;//controls[i].scale.x * controls[i].rotation.x;
        tempModelMatrix2[1] =  controls[i].scale.x * column(r, 0).y;//controls[i].scale.x * controls[i].rotation.x;
        tempModelMatrix2[2] =  controls[i].scale.x * column(r, 0).z;//controls[i].scale.x * controls[i].rotation.x;
        tempModelMatrix2[3] =  0.0f;
        tempModelMatrix2[4] =  controls[i].scale.y * column(r, 2).x;//controls[i].scale.y * controls[i].rotation.y;
        tempModelMatrix2[5] =  controls[i].scale.y * column(r, 2).y;//controls[i].scale.y * controls[i].rotation.y;
        tempModelMatrix2[6] =  controls[i].scale.y * column(r, 2).z;//controls[i].scale.y * controls[i].rotation.y;
        tempModelMatrix2[7] =  0.0f;
        tempModelMatrix2[8] =  controls[i].scale.z * column(r, 1).x;//controls[i].scale.z * controls[i].rotation.z;
        tempModelMatrix2[9] =  controls[i].scale.z * column(r, 1).y;//controls[i].scale.z * controls[i].rotation.z;
        tempModelMatrix2[10] = controls[i].scale.z * column(r, 1).z;//controls[i].scale.z * controls[i].rotation.z;
        tempModelMatrix2[11] = 0.0f;
        tempModelMatrix2[12] = controls[i].translate.x;
        tempModelMatrix2[13] = controls[i].translate.y;
        tempModelMatrix2[14] = controls[i].translate.z;
        tempModelMatrix2[15] = 1.0f;*/

        tempModelMatrix = glm::scale(tempModelMatrix, controls[i].scale);
        //cout << controls[i].path << " controls[i].translate " << to_string(controls[i].translate) << endl;
        //cout << controls[i].path << " controls[i].rotation.X " <<  controls[i].rotation.x << endl;
        //cout << controls[i].path << " controls[i].rotation.y " <<  controls[i].rotation.y << endl;
        //cout << controls[i].path << " controls[i].rotation.Z " <<  controls[i].rotation.z << endl;
        //cout << controls[i].path << " controls[i].scale " << to_string(controls[i].scale) << endl;

        string basedir = dirname(controls[i].path);
        for(int j = 0; j < tempMesh.numObjects_; j++){
            //tempMesh.objectInfo_[j].modelMatrix = controls[i].modelMatrix;
            tempMesh.objectInfo_[j].modelMatrix = tempModelMatrix;
            //tempMesh.objectInfo_[j].modelMatrix = make_mat4(tempModelMatrix2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot determine how you're storing the vertex data from the object I will define something simple:

```
struct Vertex {
    glm::vec3 position;
};

struct Mesh {
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
};
```

Now walk through all of the vertex positions and convert them to your world coordinates:

```
Mesh originalMesh = loadObjectFromFile("object.file");
Mesh convertedMesh = Mesh();

for (Vertex v : originalMesh.vertices) {
    convertedMesh.push_back(glm::vec3(v.y, v.z, v.x));
}
```

The key thing to notice here is that we're doing the following mapping:

```
x = v.y
y = v.z
z = v.x
```

If you've got other vertex data (e.g. normals, texcoords) make sure those are converted also.

Comment: I am given the "loadObjFile" function and I can't change it now. That is the reason why i need a solution for this. Also I can not transform objects with Blender or something similar. The problem is that I am arguing with my professor that this is not a good solution because some objects are rotating correctly and some are not due to different local coordinate system. I did spend the whole day today 10+ hours trying to find a solution for this. Thanks for help though :D

Comment: My answer does not require modifying ```loadObjFile``` or the original file. You convert it to your world coordinates **after** it has been loaded.

Comment: There are few objects that rotate correctly because they are in the correct world coordinate and the obj loader sends vertex data to the GPU. :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem after going through some emails with the professor and had a small error when calculating rotation matrix. I was doing it in the reverse way

```
tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.x), vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.y), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.z), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
```

instead of

```
tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.z), vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.y), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
tempModelMatrix = glm::rotate(tempModelMatrix, radians(controls[i].rotation.x), vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

Thanks for suggestions @Exide